# How can I become a certified Fusion 360 user?

Tags: 3d-design, fusion360, autodesk

I heard about the certification program from [autodesk website](https://academy.autodesk.com/about-us/certification).

How can I prepare and write this certification exam as a student? I already started using fusion 360 about a month.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Although questions on tools to design 3D printing parts is on topic, asking for a certification program may be considered off topic. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] pages for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with registering at their [website](https://academy.autodesk.com/about-us/certification) and go from there.  There is a [PDF](https://adsk-designacademy-content-live.s3.amazonaws.com/ACU_Fusion%20360_Exam%20Objectives.pdf) of a list of things you have to have mastery in:

> - SKETCHING
>
>   - Sketch Creation
>   - Create Dimensions
>   - Constraint selection and creation
>   - Edit a sketch
>   - Project Edges
>   - Edit a Sketch
> - DRAWING
>
>   - Creating a Drawing View, Base, Projected, Section, Detail
>   - Add Annotations
>   - Editing a Created View
>   - Edit Border and Titleblock
> - SCULPT
>
>   - Create a Form
>   - Edit a Form
>   - Thicken a Form
> - DIRECT MODELING
>
>   - Feature Deletion
>   - Press & Pull Tool
> - ASSEMBLY MODELING
>
>   - Create and Manage Top Level Assembly and Subassemblies
>   - Create a Component From a Body
>   - Align and Assembly Joints
>   - Interference
>   - Rigid Groups
>   - Motion Studies
> - ADVANCED MODELING
>
>   - Sweep and Loft
>   - Boundary Fill
>   - Split and Combine bodies
> - PART MODELING
>
>   - Create extrude features
>   - Apply Fillets and Chamfers
>   - Create complex hole features
>   - Create revolve features
>   - Create a pattern of features
>   - Create a shell feature
>   - Create Construction Planes and Axes
>   - Inspect command; measure, and section analysis

Comment: While the links you posted may provide the information, you should bring the information here and use the link as a reference. Links can become stale. If your answer becomes outdated in the future, it can be updated. Link only answers can be removed as an answer.